# Can I add a where clause to an IOrderedEnumerable list?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, iorderedenumerable

I have a list of arrays. Each array consists of a score and a difficulty. Read in from a text file.

This is how I get the data and order it by the score in descending order.

```
// load highscores
public void LoadScores()
{
    // loop through each line in the file
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // seperate the score from the difficulty
        lineData = line.Split(',');

        // add each line to the list
        list.Add(lineData);
    }

    // order the list by descending order
    IOrderedEnumerable<String[]> scoresDesc = list.OrderByDescending(ld => lineData[0]);

}
```

Is it possible to add the a clause to the `IOrderedEnumerable` so that it orders by the score in descending order where the difficulty is `1` ?

Comment: Yes, since method arguments (this includes extension methods) are polymorphic, and `IOrderedEnumerable` extends `IEnumerable`. The return value will be of type `IEnumerable` though, so you might want to filter before you use `OrderByDescending`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the "difficulty" is the second item in the array:

```
 IEnumerable<String[]> scoresDesc =
     list.OrderByDescending(ld => lineData[0])
         .Where(ld => lineData[1] == 1);
```

You *can* sort it afterwards, but `Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, not an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, so if you *need* it to be an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` then it's cleaner (and faster) to filter the list first:

```
 IOrderedEnumerable<String[]> scoresDesc =
     list.Where(ld => lineData[1] == 1)
         .OrderByDescending(ld => lineData[0]);
```

(this is where `var` eases some pain, since you aren't bound to the return type)

Comment: `IEnumerable<string[]> ScoresDes = list.OrderByDescending(ld => lineData[0]).Where(ld => lineData[1] == 1);` gives me this warning `operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'. What do I need to do here?

Comment: I seemed to fix this using `IEnumerable<string[]> ScoresDes = list.OrderByDescending(ld => lineData[0]).Where(ld => lineData[1].Contains("1"));` or atleast I don't get any errors.

Comment: If `lineData[1]` is a string then `lineData[1] == "1"` is appropriate. Otherwise it will pick up `"10"`, `"11"`, `"12"`, `"21"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter for those of difficulty 1, you can use the `.Where()` extension method, if you want to sort by more than one field, you can use the `.ThenBy()` extension method.

Answer (score 0):

first filter then order:

```
list.Where(x => x.difficulty == 1).OrderByDescending(ld => lineData[0]);
```

Comment: where you have `x.difficulty` how do I name my array index diffculty like this?